# How to merge GitHub and GitBench

Tags: git, github

[image]

My current Git branches are origin dev and jihoon3, and I want to safely merge them together, but how do I approach this?

I've tried git pull requests, but there are tons of crashes and it's hard to fix them one by one. Also, there's a lot of overlapping package.json, so it's hard to mess around with.

Comment: Could you expand on what "tons of crashes" means? Do you mean merge conflicts?

Comment: Ah yes the classical "push", "push" and "adsf". Git ain't gonna solve a procedural problem for you. If two people updated their package.json, then after merging, you better manually update packages.